# Can you install Minecraft Pi Edition on a Linux Cloud terminal?

Tags: linux, minecraft

There is a Cloud Linux Terminal made by Google(I think made by google) Here is the Link: https://console.cloud.google.com/
Now I was wondering if you can install Minecraft pi on the cloud service. It didn't work but if there is a way, I would like to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we need more context. The Raspberry Pi runs the ARM architecture, which is normally present in embedded devices. If you ran a cloud instance with this architecture, then the Pi version of Minecraft server should run without problems.
If your instance runs AMD64 (which is the most likely), and you're running Ubuntu or Debian, then you should install the package as normal, here's a guide to it: https://www.linode.com/docs/game-servers/how-to-set-up-minecraft-server-on-ubuntu-or-debian/
If you have further questions, please give us a little more info.

Comment: I have intel windows 10 pc, and also a raspberry pi. Forget the Raspberry pi for now, on an intel PC, using this cloud Linux terminal, can you install Minecraft Pi?

Comment: You can't install Minecraft Pi on a non-Pi because of architecture. You should install Minecraft for Linux.

Comment: Oh OK thx for letting me know